# fwrite return int(0) on web server but not on Wamp

Tags: php, linux, wamp, fwrite

I am unable to find any issue with this code on my shared hosting. It is returning `(int)0`, but on my wamp server it is returning the correct bytes. The IP address is taken from gametracker public servers.

**Code**

```
$socket = fsockopen( 'udp://51.75.36.115', '25565' );
$packet = pack("c3N", 0xFE, 0xFD, 0x09, 2);
$fwrite = fwrite($socket, $packet, strlen($packet));
var_dump( $fwrite);
```

**Response**

```
int(0)
```

I have checked all the php configurations and all modules. I am not getting anything in the error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was server restrictions, you cannot do this on shared hosting, you need a cloud or dedicated server.